# WebRequest can't retrieve video info?

Tags: c#, webrequest

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://istr03.izlesene.com/data/videos/7213/7213704-360_2-103k.mp4/e5ae7a74a30f645c6fc0c5aa0fde9076/531B29B7"));
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
    double boyut = response.ContentLength / 1024 / 1024;
    string tip = response.ContentType;
}
```

This code is working for other sites but for this url,  an exception is raised; *(500) internal server error*.

What could be different that the code fails for this url?

Comment: what error you are experiencing? Remember that HEAD method depends upon server and it may or may not be supported. So if HEAD method is not supported by server, you will receive and error

Comment: can't get video size or content type i tried request.method another method not working this site..

Comment: I get video info over 1000 site using this code

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: (500) internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an [User-Agent http header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43). This specific server expects that probably to sniff the capabilities of the client.

Adapt your code to get the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the [UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(
             new Uri("http://your url here"));
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        request.UserAgent = "spider/1.0"; 

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            double boyut = response.ContentLength / 1024 / 1024;
            string tip = response.ContentType;
        }
```

The content-length of your url is: 13381446
and the content-type is: video/mp4

Comment: There is no member 'Useragent' of 'System.Net.WebClient' ?

Comment: Ohh sorry I use HttpWebRequest ok now.

Answer (score 1):

I did use fiddler to see what is going on. the url you provided redirected to another [URL](http://sstr06.izlesene.com/data/videos/7213/7213704-360_2-103k.mp4?token=WCk3CCIxJYVC0ESMOs1cFw&ts=1394210720) .

```
HEAD http://istr03.izlesene.com/data/videos/7213/7213704-360_2-103k.mp4/e5ae7a74a30f645c6fc0c5aa0fde9076/531B29B7 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: istr03.izlesene.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Via: 1.1 81.212.99.207 (McAfee Web Gateway 7.3.2.3.0.16052)
Date: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 14:45:20 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Location: http://sstr06.izlesene.com/data/videos/7213/7213704-360_2-103k.mp4?token=WCk3CCIxJYVC0ESMOs1cFw&ts=1394210720
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
```

So you need to parse Location from first response and do another request to server with HEAD method and you will get content length of video.

```
HEAD http://sstr06.izlesene.com/data/videos/7213/7213704-360_2-103k.mp4?token=WCk3CCIxJYVC0ESMOs1cFw&ts=1394210720 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: sstr06.izlesene.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 81.212.99.207 (McAfee Web Gateway 7.3.2.3.0.16052)
Date: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 14:45:21 GMT
ETag: "53037f98-cc2f46"
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 15:43:20 GMT
Content-Length: 13381446
```

Comment: And you have to provide User-Agent header. Without this header request returns 500 .